# Pyside set shortcut with mouse button to the QAction

Tags: button, mouse, pyside, shortcut, qaction

I want to set shortcut to the QAction as "Ctrl + Left Mouse Button", but can't figure out how to do this. For keyboard shortcuts I do like this:

```
someAction = QtGui.QAction("DoSomething", self, shortcut="Ctrl+S")
```

Anyone has a suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What would you click on?

Comment: On QMainWindow>QWebView.